No instrumentation registered! using Android Studio Iguana and Cucumber
I'm using the latest version of Android Studio Iguana and I'm trying to run some Cucumber tests with an app I developed. I have set up Gradle and created the necessary files to try out Cucumber. However, when I tried to run the .feature file, I encountered the following error:
The error:
may 15, 2024 10:46:09 A. M. cucumber.runtime.java.ObjectFactoryLoader loadSingleObjectFactory
ADVERTENCIA: Use deprecated reflections to load ObjectFactory.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation.
    at androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.java:45)
    at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule.<init>(ActivityTestRule.java:148)
    at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule.<init>(ActivityTestRule.java:124)
    at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule.<init>(ActivityTestRule.java:107)
    at es.unizar.eina.T223_comidas.test.RunStepsDefinition.<init>(RunStepsDefinition.java:45)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:145)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:342)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.picocontainer.PicoFactory.getInstance(PicoFactory.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:57)
    at cucumber.runner.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:50)
    at cucumber.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:65)
    at cucumber.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:50)
    at cucumber.runner.PickleStepTestStep.run(PickleStepTestStep.java:43)
    at cucumber.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:46)
    at cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:50)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime$1.run(Runtime.java:103)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(Runtime.java:271)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:100)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:26)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:8)
    at ✽.There are 0 dishes

This is my set up:
Paths:

.features location: app/src/androidTest/assets/features/createdish.features.
Cucumber options: app/src/androidTest/java/es/unizar/eina/T233_comidas/test/RunCukesTest.
The steps it should run: app/src/androidTest/java/es/unizar/eina/T233_comidas/test/RunStepsDefinition.

My .feature file:
Feature: The App lets the user create a dish

  The dish is added to the database when the
  user creates a dish fulfilling all the required
  information

  Scenario: Create a dish
    Given There are 0 dishes
    When Add a dish
    Then There should be 1 dishes

My Cucumber options:
package es.unizar.eina.T223_comidas.cucumber;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;

@CucumberOptions(
        glue = { "es.unizar.eina.T223_comidas.test" }, tags = "~@wip" , features = { "features" }
)

public class RunCukesTest {
}

My steps:
package es.unizar.eina.T223_comidas.test;

import androidx.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions;
import androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;

import org.junit.Rule;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

import es.unizar.eina.T223_comidas.ui.MainActivity;

public class RunStepsDefinition {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> rule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Given("There are {int} dishes")
    public void there_are_dishes(Integer int1) {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new cucumber.api.PendingException();
    }

    @When("Add a dish")
    public void add_a_dish() {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new cucumber.api.PendingException();
    }

    @Then("There should be {int} dishes")
    public void there_should_be_dishes(Integer int1) {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new cucumber.api.PendingException();
    }

}


I've been trying out multiple dependencies, so it is possible to exist collisions between them, not sure if that is possible. I need to use andoridx.
My app gradle:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'es.unizar.eina.T223_comidas'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "es.unizar.eina.T223_comidas"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        // testInstrumentationRunner "io.cucumber.android.runner.CucumberAndroidJUnitRunner"

        // testInstrumentationRunner "cucumber.api.android.CucumberAndroidJUnitRunner"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.3'
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}
/*
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}*/

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$rootProject.appCompatVersion"

    // Dependencies for working with Architecture components
    // You'll probably have to update the version numbers in build.gradle (Project)

    // Room components
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.03.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.03.00')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"

    // Lifecycle components
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$rootProject.lifecycleVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:$rootProject.lifecycleVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$rootProject.lifecycleVersion"

    // UI
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2'
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$rootProject.constraintLayoutVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$rootProject.materialVersion"

    // Testing
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$rootProject.junitVersion"
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:$rootProject.junit5Version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$rootProject.coreTestingVersion"
    androidTestImplementation ("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$rootProject.espressoVersion", {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$rootProject.androidxJunitVersion"
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'

    // Assertions
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    // UI testing with Espresso
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    androidTestImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-android:4.4.1'
// Se recomienda no actualizar la versión de io.cucumber:cucumber-picocontainer
    androidTestImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-picocontainer:4.4.0'
    androidTestUtil 'androidx.test:orchestrator:1.4.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
}

My project gradle:
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '8.2.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
}
ext {
    appCompatVersion = '1.6.1'
    constraintLayoutVersion = '2.1.4'
    coreTestingVersion = '2.2.0'
    lifecycleVersion = '2.7.0'
    materialVersion = '1.11.0'
    roomVersion = '2.6.1'
    // testing
    junitVersion = '4.13.2'
    espressoVersion = '3.5.1'
    androidxJunitVersion = '1.1.5'
    junit5Version = '5.10.2'
}

My Android Manifest:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/logo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.PlatoEdit"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.Platos"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.Pedidos"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.PedidoEdit"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

